# autocad lisp - command counter and storing data

Tags: lisp, autocad, autolisp

I want to monitor my commands and save that data in a text file on the server, so people can see how many times (in 1 week, 2 weeks, 1 month) I used the `line` command, `pline` command, etc.

That text file continues counting all the time.

I already have `acaddoc.lsp`,and I have this lisp from Lee Mac (thanks) that is counting the commands, but I don't want them to print on the screen, only count them in the text file.

```lisp
(defun c:viewcmd nil
   (if (or cmdspy:endlst cmdspy:unklst cmdspy:canlst)
       (progn
           (mapcar 'cmdspy:print
              '("Completed Commands" "Cancelled Commands" "Unknown Commands")
               (list cmdspy:endlst cmdspy:canlst cmdspy:unklst)
           )
           (textscr)
       )
       (princ "\nNo command history found.")
   )
   (princ)
)
(defun cmdspy:updatelist ( cmd lst / itm )
   (if (setq itm (assoc cmd lst))
       (subst (cons cmd (1+ (cdr itm))) itm lst)
       (cons  (cons cmd 1) lst)
   )
)
(defun cmdspy:print ( hed lst / len )
   (if lst
       (progn
           (setq len (/ (- 30 (strlen hed)) 2))
           (princ "\n\n ")
           (repeat len (princ "-"))
           (princ " ") (princ  hed) (princ " ")
           (repeat len (princ "-")) 
           (foreach itm (vl-sort lst '(lambda ( a b ) (> (cdr a) (cdr b))))
               (princ  (strcat "\n " (car itm) " "))
               (repeat (- 30 (strlen (car itm)) (strlen (itoa (cdr itm)))) (princ "."))
               (princ  (strcat " " (itoa (cdr itm))))
           )
           (princ (strcat "\n TOTAL: " (itoa (apply '+ (mapcar 'cdr lst)))))
       )
   )
)
(   (lambda nil
       (vl-load-com)
       (mapcar
          '(lambda ( s1 s2 )
               (eval
                   (list 'defun s1 '( obj arg )
                       (list 'setq s2 (list 'cmdspy:updatelist '(strcase (car arg)) s2))
                   )
               )
           )
          '(cmdspy:endfun cmdspy:unkfun cmdspy:canfun)
          '(cmdspy:endlst cmdspy:unklst cmdspy:canlst)
       )
       (if (null cmdspy:reactor)
           (setq cmdspy:reactor
               (vlr-command-reactor "cmdspy"
                  '(
                       (:vlr-commandended     . cmdspy:endfun)
                       (:vlr-unknowncommand   . cmdspy:unkfun)
                       (:vlr-commandcancelled . cmdspy:canfun)
                   )
               )
           )
       )
       (princ)
   )
)
; Edited July 21, 2015 by Lee Mac
```

Answer (score 1):

In function

```
cmdspy:print
```

open file:

```
(setq des (open "C:\\MyTextFile.txt" "a"))
```

than change `princ` to `(write-line ..... des)`

at the end of function `cmdspy:print` close file

```
(close des)
```